# I cannot post large text data to SQL in php

Tags: php, sql-server

i have created a form in html containing text area and input and submit button.
Now i want to post large text data to SQL varchar max 8000 but it fails and accept only small amount of text.

Comment: i didnt get any error when i press submit it reopen the same page and when i submit small amout of text its say message send successfully

Comment: i dont understand debug error as i am begginner

Comment: any example please

Comment: <?PHP
// Posting answer
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/karachi");
$date = date("d/m/y");
SESSION_START();
$u_id = $_SESSION["u_id"];
include "database.php";
if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
$p_id = $_POST["p_id"];
 $post = $_POST['post'];
  $que="Insert into answer value('', '$p_id', '$u_id',  '$post', '$date')";
   if(mysql_query($que)) {
$que2= mysql_query("Insert into noti value('', '$p_id', '$u_id', '$poster', '$date', '1')");
    echo "<script>alert('Message send successfully')</script>";             
                                      
          }

Comment: i commented the code any changes u suggess

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a server configuration. If you're working with PHP under Linux or similar, you can control it using .htaccess configuration file, like so:

## set max post size

php_value post_max_size 20M

Answer (score 1):

See php.ini file, I'm have this error with XML sending, php have a limits to post data. Change line php_value post_max_size = 30M in configuration file